# Airflow -D not working, not running in the background

Tags: airflow

I can start webserver normally, with the command `airflow webserver`. but when I use `airflow webserver -D`, it shows:

```
/data/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py:65: DeprecationWarning: The elasticsearch_host option in [elasticsearch] has been renamed to host - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
  ELASTICSEARCH_HOST = conf.get('elasticsearch', 'HOST')
/data/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py:67: DeprecationWarning: The elasticsearch_log_id_template option in [elasticsearch] has been renamed to log_id_template - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
  ELASTICSEARCH_LOG_ID_TEMPLATE = conf.get('elasticsearch', 'LOG_ID_TEMPLATE')
/data/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py:69: DeprecationWarning: The elasticsearch_end_of_log_mark option in [elasticsearch] has been renamed to end_of_log_mark - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
  ELASTICSEARCH_END_OF_LOG_MARK = conf.get('elasticsearch', 'END_OF_LOG_MARK')
[2019-12-25 06:37:49,537] {settings.py:252} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=855
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
[2019-12-25 06:37:50,031] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2019-12-25 06:37:50,031] {dagbag.py:92} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /data/projects/airflow/dags
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
=================================================================
```

Then, there is not any process running in the background later. I check with the command`ps -ef|grep airflow`.

The version of Airflow is `1.10.6`.

In previous versions, `-D` used to work fine

Comment: Do you stacktrace of any error?

Comment: not any error. If start without -D,  It's normal.

Comment: Happy to dig into this with you, are you on Airflow Slack ? https://apache-airflow-slack.herokuapp.com/

Comment: thanks for your help. yes I'm on official Ariflow Slack. apache-airflow.slack.com

Answer (score 3):

If you can run `airflow webserver` normally. No errors for `airflow webserver -D`, and you can not find the process running as airflow webserver.

It must be you killed the background process of `airflow webserver -D`, and you didn't delete the pid file of airflow webserver.

You can go to the `$AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow` directory, check the pid files. If exists and not empty, delete it and retry:

```
cd $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow
rm airflow-webserver*.pid
airflow webserver -D
```